# What is the difference between OpenLiberty and WebSphere Liberty?

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

Recently IBM created a new open source project called "OpenLiberty" that is largely shared with the codebase for WebSphere Liberty.

What is the difference between OpenLiberty vs. WebSphere Liberty?  What features do I get with the free open source version, and what extra features are available with WebSphere Liberty?

Comment: This question being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356775/5764553).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

OpenLiberty contains a subset of what is available with the larger "WebSphere Liberty" server.  Namely, OpenLiberty contains full support for Java EE 7.0 8.0, and MicroProfile features.

With WebSphere Liberty comes the "production grade" features that help with scaling up to a larger cluster of servers, as well as metric and monitoring features.

Here is a visualization of the feature breakdown.  It will change in the future, but gives a rough idea of how the feature organization works:

[image: Open Liberty and WebSphere Liberty features]

#### Here are links to the current list of OpenLiberty / WebSphere Liberty features:

- [Current OpenLiberty features](https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/feature/)
- [Current WebSphere Liberty features](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html)

Comment: Is there an updated version to this list?

Comment: @DavidZ I don't have an updated image, but I've updated my answer to include links to the respective feature pages for OpenLiberty and WebSphere Liberty, which will always be up-to-date in the future

Comment: Great explanatory image. I am currently trying to get the list of differences between Core and Base versions and this helped... Not sure if this still remains this way as Open Liberty is nowadays full-profile compliant, isn't it? Any source to get and updated list of differences between Core and Base (they are still separate licenses, right?)